# How to disable Twitter Bootstrap 3 or force a certain size?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have searched a bit and found a suggestion to use a meta tag but `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200">` but that doest work. How can I force a certain layout to show, regardless of the screen (document) size?

I need to embed various website things in an frame for a CRM preview, I disable headers and footers progrmatically to save space - but bootstrap shows the TABLET layout version... which is taking too much space in the iframe.

I just want it show the full size `lg` layout regardless of what the document size is.

Answer (score 1):

To disable responsiveness in bootstrap you have to do additional steps

most important being number 2

> ### Steps to disable responsive views
>
> To disable responsive features, follow these steps. See it in action in the modified template below.
>
> 1. Remove (or just don't add) the viewport  mentioned in the CSS docs
> 2. Remove the max-width on the .container for all grid tiers with max-width: none !important; and set a regular width like width: 970px;. Be sure that this comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the !important with media queries or some selector-fu.
> 3. If using navbars, undo all the navbar collapsing and expanding behavior (this is too much to show here, so peep the example).
> 4. For grid layouts, make use of .col-xs-* classes in addition to or in place of the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales up to all resolutions, so you're set there.
>
> You'll still need Respond.js for IE8 (since our media queries are still there and need to be picked up). This just disables the "mobile site" of Bootstrap.

[Disable responsiveness](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)

## Addtionally

A few elements won't be fixed width. -[See the none responsive demo here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/)

To change the extra resizing which in your case doesn't seem like you need would need to edit `LESS` or `SASS` file.

You will need to change the breakpoints by editing the variable.less [file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less) by making all of them 1200px or something.

```
//== Media queries breakpoints
//
//## Define the breakpoints at which your layout will change, adapting to different screen sizes.

// Extra small screen / phone
//** Deprecated `@screen-xs` as of v3.0.1
@screen-xs:                  480px;
//** Deprecated `@screen-xs-min` as of v3.2.0
@screen-xs-min:              @screen-xs;
//** Deprecated `@screen-phone` as of v3.0.1
@screen-phone:               @screen-xs-min;

// Small screen / tablet
//** Deprecated `@screen-sm` as of v3.0.1
@screen-sm:                  768px;
@screen-sm-min:              @screen-sm;
//** Deprecated `@screen-tablet` as of v3.0.1
@screen-tablet:              @screen-sm-min;

// Medium screen / desktop
//** Deprecated `@screen-md` as of v3.0.1
@screen-md:                  992px;
@screen-md-min:              @screen-md;
//** Deprecated `@screen-desktop` as of v3.0.1
@screen-desktop:             @screen-md-min;

// Large screen / wide desktop
//** Deprecated `@screen-lg` as of v3.0.1
@screen-lg:                  1200px;
@screen-lg-min:              @screen-lg;
//** Deprecated `@screen-lg-desktop` as of v3.0.1
@screen-lg-desktop:          @screen-lg-min;
```

Comment: I want responsiveness on my original site, just when I load the site in iframe using a query param, I disable allot of stuff and just want to show the lg sizes. So.. it seems like I should overload new CSS with this non-responding stuff you mentioned? I dont want to add or change any markup but I can overload CSS... or maybe not load the normal one and load this non respsonive one... is that what you saying? :)

Comment: Yea that makes sense now when I re read it 7 times... thanks. I will try it on Monday. Im pretty sure this is the answer

Comment: ya its simple actually if you edit the sass/less file- since its iframe there is no conflict issues